# AspectJ for Logger on File

Tags: java, logging, aspectj, logfile

I'm trying to create a log file with AspectJ, 
output should be written to a file
the log file has a specific syntax:

```
START

"THREAD_ID";"METHOD_NAME";"begin_or_end METHOD";"instant time"

STOP
```

the code does not work :(

you can help me?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;

aspect Trace{

    private static File salva;
    private static FileWriter fw;
    pointcut traceMethods() : (execution(* *(..))&& !cflow(within(Trace)));

    before(): traceMethods(){
        salva = new File(".\trace.csv");
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(salva,true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Signature sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
        String line =""+ thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getLine();
        String sourceName = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getWithinType().getCanonicalName();
        Logger.getLogger("Tracing").log(
                Level.INFO, 
                "Call from "
                    +  sourceName
                    +" line " +
                    line
                    +" to " +sig.getDeclaringTypeName() + "." + sig.getName()

        );
        writeFile(sig);
        try {
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void writeFile(Signature sig){
        long temp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //inizio esecuzione traccia:
        try {
            fw.write("START\n");
            fw.write("S02034;");
            fw.write(sig.getDeclaringTypeName()+"."+sig.getName()+";"+temp+";"+"a\n");
            fw.write("STOP\n");
            fw.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: To help us narrow down the problem, what is the specific error that you are getting when you try to run the code?

Comment: Can you post example of what you get in the files?

Comment: how can I tell when a method terms ?, ie, I can understand that a method is called, but I can not capture the moment that the method ends. how can I do this with AspectJ? you have to use a new pointcut?

Comment: I resolved my Problem :D
Thk  :D